# how do i insert line number in java code block using markdown?

Tags: java, markdown

I use markdown to write my blog.When I write a java code block,i wanna insert the line number like

[image: this]

Comment: Probably easier to use embedded HTML code blocks

Comment: Add gist from GitHub.

Comment: depends on your markdown-engine. e.g. pandoc has the ability to put in line numbers.